# Can we use SQL Server indexing in PowerBI import query

Tags: sql-server, indexing, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have created an index in SQL Server for one of the column. Now I need to use the table in PowerBI. How to use index in that case.

Comment: I think this document help you.  [Document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/using-the-storedprocedure-with-select-sql-query-in-web-api/)

Comment: SQL Server will automatically use an index if it helps it to execute the query.